# Passing a non-constant to a constant - *(new foo()) and foo() difference when passing as argument

Tags: c++

I wanted to know what the difference is between these two. I was expecting both of them to have the same behavior as statement A

```
void myfunctReference(foo& f) 
{
        std::cout << "Function called";
}
```

Here are callers

statement A:

```
 myfunctReference(foo()); //Fail - OK Agreed. Because a temp is being sent as a parameter to a function who parameter is not constant. temporaries can only bind to constant references
```

statement B:

```
myfunctReference(*(new foo())); //Allowed - Why ? isnt *(new foo()) a temp ?
```

Comment: `new foo()` returns a temporary pointer that points to an lvalue designating the object.

Comment: new allocates memory for the object, and unless you delete it, it will leak. So no, it isn't a temporary, but you mustn't do that.

Comment: I know I should not do that I am just just asking out of curiosity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why ? isnt *(new foo()) a temp ?

No, it isn't a "temp". It is an lvalue expression, referring to the newed object, an object that is alive until someone calls `delete` on it. It is perfectly fine to bind a non-const lvalue reference to such an expression.

What it is is a memory leak.